# How to automatically fit a paragraph into a div box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using JQuery to prepend a `<p>` element into a div however if `mainButtonText` in the `p` element is too long, it will be outside of the div.

http://puu.sh/mvm7F/a99aba0b1e.jpg

I want it to look like this: http://puu.sh/mvmEy/c17db01e4a.jpg

Is it also possible to automatically resize the text font size?

html:

```
<div id="mainButton"></div>
```

css:

```css
#mainButton {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #808080;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05), inset 0  0 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), 0 5px 5px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#mainButton:hover {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

#mainButton:active {
  top: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0 0 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), inset 0 6px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

javascript:

```
function changeMainButton() {
  'use strict';
  $('#mainButton').empty();
  $('#mainButton').prepend('<p>' + mainButtonText + '</p>');
}
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: In title you wrote fit, but in your screenshot you hide text. what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
#mainButton {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It seems to fit everything into the div, however some of the text is not showing. http://puu.sh/mvmPZ/171b075df0.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment, not realising that you were the same person that posted this.Here is an extended view http://puu.sh/mvnEV/fd689fffa5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can make the text adjust to its container using

```
#mainButton {
 word-wrap: break-word;    
}
```

You can also resize the font size in relation to its parent element using javascript like http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/ or http://fittextjs.com/ but if you want to control it in granular use @media, em and rem